# Add different iCloud email to existing AppleID

Tags: icloud, apple-id

Lets say an AppleID is created with the iCloud email address `somebdy@icloud.com` (misspelled).

Is there any way to correct the iCloud email to `somebody@icloud.com`? Creating a new AppleID would lose old purchases and is not an option.

Is iCloud permanently linked to an AppleID? Is there a way to change the `@icloud.com` address?

According to [this Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE40), renaming the iCloud/AppleID prefix is possible *as long as it is not an `@mac.com` or `@me.com`* (quoted from link).

However, when I follow the instructions, I only see an option to add a new primary email, I don't see the same screen as in the last illustration in that article.

Apple's screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

My screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Even though the Apple support article referred to doesn't specificaly say this (I'm assuming it's because @icloud.com was only introduced recently and the article was never updated), what goes for @me.com and @mac.com goes for @icloud.com (they're all aliases for the same address).

ie, read: *Some Apple IDs, like those ending in @mac.com, @me.com `or @icloud.com`, can't be changed.*

So no, unfortunately you won't be able to change.

iCloud: About your icloud.com, me.com, and mac.com email addresses
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5441

Answer (score 0):

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2622 you could try making an alias.

You could also change the email associated with the account. I don't actually use my me account for anything.

I don't think you can make a new iCloud account and link that without a new device. I'm not really sure about how to get a new iCloud account really. I do know that you can't change your iCloud email address; it's stuck as whatever you made it as originally.

Answer (score 0):

While your Apple ID is in the form of an email address, that email address does not need to be used for anything associated with the Apple ID. Your primary email address, for contact with Apple, does NOT need to be the same as your Apple ID, it can be anything.

In otherwords, you can have an Apple ID that is `somebody@icloud.com` but use the primary email address of `somebody@gmail.com`.

In fact, my Apple ID is actually an old email address I no longer use, but nothing associated with the Apple ID ever gets sent to this old email address (which would not work anyway). Instead, I changed by primary email to my current email address, which has no impact on the Apple ID.

Answer (score -3):

You can create a new iCloud account easily on a mac by creating a new user.