# Two different Apple IDs with two different @icloud.com mails

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I have a complicated problem. It started when I created an apple id with icloud email. Later after some months, I created anther apple id with a new icloud mail. Now, I am using this new apple id on my apple devices.

My Problem:
I need to use my old icloud email on my new apple id. In other words, I want to terminate my current (new) icloud mail and move the old icloud mail so I can use it with the new apple id instead.

I tried different ways, but no solution! Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - if you really have [two different AppleID each with different @icloud/@me/@mac addressed - they cannot be merged or swapped one for the other](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69361/add-different-icloud-email-to-existing-appleid). If you just want to use the @icloud.com to log in to one AppleID that's also known by a different email address - you can do that easily by changing the username on each device.

See [Apple ID - Want to make my xxx@icloud.com primary Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80785/apple-id-want-to-make-my-xxxicloud-com-primary-apple-id)

If you have two AppleID - the best you can to towards merging them might be to make a family plan and share purchases and migrate mail/contact/calendar data off the account you wish to avoid.

See [Renaming iCloud mail address](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217581/renaming-icloud-mail-address) for that.

Comment: One day... one day... they may let us merge :/ I've had my iTunes account since 04, but my iCloud [me.com] since 09 & have had to juggle for all this time.

Comment: Now that you can family share - I doubt merge would happen. Imagine the mess if someone social engineers them to merge an account when they shouldn't, @Tetsujin

Comment: Can you rename the old account to something else and add the old name that you want to keep as an alias on the new account?

Comment: @bmike - I eventually managed to get both into family sharing - it's frustrated all attempts until I realised that the me.com account was using the real.com address as payment method & vice versa. I had to set up a new account on the Mac so I could sign into both at once, then took it from there... I just hope I've not further complicated all this ;-)

Comment: @Vitalydotn - were it so simple ;-) One account is all my shared calendars etc, that's the existing Family Organiser, the other is all my iTunes & App Store purchases for the past 15 years... let's hope I finally got it after being able to join my 'real' self to the Family at long last.

Comment: @Tetsujin maybe I'm misunderstanding something. You absolutely can log in with the purchase account into the iTunes/Mac/iOS app stores, while keeping the other account with your calendars and such logged into the iCloud section. That'd let you use both for the purpose you just described. Also if it's iOS, it'll even back up which account you're using for what, so if you restore from backup it'll ask you for passwords of both, and download apps accordingly.

Comment: @Vitalydotn - yes, except the Organiser account wasn't the one with the 15-year purchase history, it was the wrong way round. Believe me, this has confused me for years - at least I now managed to get them all under one Organiser account, at long last :)

Comment: Excellent comments @Tetsujin - I'd welcome an answer or edit to mine if I can't find a better question for how to resolve this. Many people will be in your shoes.

Comment: @bmike - I'm still trying to work out how to turn what was essentially several years of vaguely poking at stuff until it worked into a coherent addition or answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. The best solution for me was to forward the mail from the old Apple ID to the new Apple ID. This way you can migrate over time to the new Apple ID.

1. Log in in icloud.com using your old Apple ID.
2. Open Mail.
3. Click Actions (cog in bottom-left) and choose Preferences.
4. Select Forward my email to and enter your new Apple ID.
5. Click Done.

You can also select "Delete message after forwarding" when you're sure it's all working correctly.

I know it's not strictly what you want, but I found it the best solution to having an old and new account.

Comment: thanks this can also be a solution. but I don't prefer it!